# Question related to PDE , Solve IBVP

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose that an external force per unit length given by

$f$($t$, $x$) = $h$($x$) sin ($ωt$), $ω$ > $0$

with $h$ piecewise continuous on the interval [$0$, $L$] acts on a string with fixed
endpoints at $x$ = $0$ and $x$ = $L$. Solve the IBVP

$∂_{tt}u$ = v$^2$$∂_{xx}u$ + $f(t, x)$ $∀$ $t$ > $0$, $x$ $∈$ ($0$, $L$),

$u(0, x) = 0  ,∀ x ∈ [0, L],$

$∂_{t}u(t, x)$$|_{t=0}$ = $0$  $∀ x ∈ [0, L]$,

$u(t, 0) = 0 = u(t, L) ∀ t ≥ 0.$

---

Here are my thoughts :

I assume its homogenous form with forced, hence we get 
$u(x,t)$ = $(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$ $u_{n}(t)$ $sin$ ($\frac{n\pi x}{L}$))

$u_{n}(t)$ functions to be determined

For each fixed $t$ we can determine Fourier series of $f(x,t)$ = $(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$ $f_{n}(t)$ $sin$ ($\frac{n\pi x}{L}$))

Where coefficients  $f_{n}(t)$ is given by $f_{n}(t)$ = $\frac{2}{L}$ $\int_{{0}}^{L}$ $f (x,t)$ $sin$ ($\frac{n\pi x}{L}$) $dx$

$f_{n}(t)$ = $\frac{2}{L}$ $\int_{{0}}^{L}$ $h (x)$ $sin(ωt$) $sin$ ($\frac{n\pi x}{L}$) $dx$

With proper integral properties $f_{n}(t)$  substitute in above PDE

$(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$ [$u$$''$ + ($\frac{n\pi x}{L}$)$^2$ $u_{n}(t)$] ] $sin$ ($\frac{n\pi x}{L}$)) =  $(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$ $f_{n}(t)$ $sin$ ($\frac{n\pi x}{L}$))

By equating coefficients:

$u_{n}$$''(t)$ + ($\frac{n\pi x}{L}$)$^2$ $u_{n}(t)$ = $f_{n}(t)$

So these are nonhomogeneous-constant coefficients that can be solved using the variation of parameters.

$u_{n}(t)$ = $\frac{L}{n\pi x}$  $\int_{{0}}^{t}$ $f_{n}(s)$ $sin$ ($\frac{n\pi x}{L}$)$(t-s)$ $ds$

So based on $h(x)$ we get $f_{n}(s)$ then subsititute we get formal solution of PDE

$u(x,t)$ = $(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$ $u_{n}(t)$ $sin$ ($\frac{n\pi x}{L}$))

$u(x,t)$ = $(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$ {$\frac {L}{n\pi x}$ $\int_{{0}}^{t}$ $f_{n}(s)$  $sin$ ($\frac{n\pi x}{L}$)$(t-s)$ $ds$} $sin$ ($\frac{n\pi x}{L}$)

In the end, we got the solution by the method of separation of variables

Am I solving right? 
Because it is a project question and I want to make sure to get a full mark on it